# c# interop excel: Write 1D array to excel range

Tags: c#, arrays, excel-interop

I want to copy an 1D array to a column range in excel. I'm using `interop` for this purpose.

I have already tried these things:

- `range.get_Resize(Ary.Length, 1).Value2 = Ary;`
- `range.set_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, Ary);`
- and as simple as `range.Value = Ary;`

I have tried using even `range.value2`, but these things copy the very first index value in the array to the entire range.

So say suppose, if there are 200 rows in the range and the array contains integers 101-300, than only 101 is copied throughout the range with the above tried methods.

Can anyone please help me with this? It would be more helpful if someone can explain me this strange behavior! Thanks in advance.

> Note: I know I can do it through a *for loop*, but that takes time. I would surely like to know a method which takes less than a minute to iterate a million rows.

Comment: In my old (Visual Basic) code, I can set Value directly. What type is your ´Ary´.

Comment: Its a string array. But the problem is, I have tried this even with int array and object array with no luck. I don't understand why it isn't working.

Comment: Could you try making range a 'dynamic' variable? Also: When the array is too large, the set of 'Value' throws an exception, and I set the data one by one.

Comment: As you suggested, I tried with dynamic variable but didn't work. Still the same behavior.

Comment: Latest suggestion: Try it in Visual Basic. Yes I know, but in old&dark ages of .Net 1.0 it was unbeatable for interop, specially with late binding. The world is a better place now. We've added a .vb project to our solution that is otherwise in C#.

Comment: Yep! I agree with that but that's not a working solution for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seriously don't know what exactly is wrong with the above methods. But I found the solution:

```
Excel.Range range = sheetSource.UsedRange.Columns[columnIndx];
range.Value = application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Ary);
```